# Data parsing in pandas, python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date, text-parsing

I have an excel file with many columns, one of them, 'Column3' is date with some text in it, basically it looks like that:

```
26/05/20
XXX
YYY
12/05/2020
```

The data is written in DD/MM/YY format but pandas, just like excel, thinks that 12/05/2020 it's 05 Dec 2020 while it is 12 May 2020. (My windows is set to american date format)

Important note: when I open stock excel file, cells with 12/05/2020 already are Date type, trying to convert it to text it gives me 44170 which will give me wrong date if I just reformat it into DD/MM/YY

I added this line of code:

```
iport pandas as pd
    
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%y')
df = pd.read_excel("my_file.xlsx", parse_dates=['Column3'], date_parser=dateparse)
```

But the text in the column generates an error.

```
ValueError: time data 'XXX' does not match format '%d/%m/%y'
```

I went a step further and manually removed all text (obviously I can't do it all the time) to see whether it works or nor, but then I got following error

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%y')
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime
```

I also tried this:

```
df['Column3'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Column3, format ='%d/%m/%y', errors="coerce") 
# if I make errors="ignore" it doesn't change anything.
```

in that case my 26/05/20 was correctly converted to 26 May 2020 but I lost all my text data(it's ok) and other dates which didn't match with my format argument. Because previously they were recognized as American type date.

**My objective is** to convert the data in Column3 to the same format so I could apply filters with pandas.
I think it's couple solutions:

1. tell Pandas to not convert text to date at all (but it is already saved as Date type in stock file, will it work?)
2. somehow ignore text values and use date_parser=  method co convert add dates to DD/MM/YY
3. with help of pd.to_datetime convert 26/05/20 to 26 May 2020 and than convert 2020-09-06 00:00:00 to 9 June 2020 (seems to be the simplest one but ignore argument doesn't work.)

Here's link to small sample file https://easyupload.io/ca5p6w

Comment: Share a small sample file with all the edge cases you have, and the expected solution, then we can test this

Comment: Whats your objective here? can you add your intended output.

Comment: @MaartenFabré, Datanovice - thanks for helping to make question more clear. I added a link to a sample file and specified the objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer, since it's too long for a comment

The problem originates in Excel. If I open it in Excel, I see 2 strings that look like dates  `26/05/20`, `05/12/2020` and `06/02/2020`. Note the difference between the `20` and `2020` On lines 24 and 48 I see dates in Column4. This seems to indicate the Excel is put together. Is this Excel assembled by copy-paste, or programmatically?

loading it with just `pd.read_excel` gives these results for the dates:

- 26/05/20
- 2020-12-05 00:00:00
- 2020-02-06 00:00:00

If I do `df["Column3"].apply(type)`
gives me

- str
- <class 'datetime.datetime'>
- <class 'datetime.datetime'>

So in the Excel file these are marked as datetime.

Loading them with `df = pd.read_excel(DATA_DIR / "sample.xlsx", dtype={"Column3": str})` changes the type of all to `str`, but does not change the output.

If you open the extract the file, and go look at the xml file `xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml` directly and look for cell C26, you see it as `44170`, while C5 is `6`, which is a reference to `26/05/20` in `xl/sharedStrings.xml`

How do you 'make' this Excel file? This can best be solved in how this file is put together.

---

## Workaround

As a workaround, you can convert the dates piecemeal. The different format allows this:

```
format1 = "%d/%m/%y"
format2 = "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"
```

Then you can do `pd.to_datetime(dates, format=format1, errors="coerce")` to only get the first dates, and `NaT` for the ones not according to the format. Then  you use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) to fill the voids.

```
dates = df["Column3"]  # of the one imported with dtype={"Column3": str}
dates_parsed = (
    pd.to_datetime(dates, format=format1, errors="coerce")
    .combine_first(pd.to_datetime(dates, format=format2, errors="coerce"))
    .astype(object)
    .combine_first(dates)
)
```

The `astype(object)` is needed to fill in the empty places with the string values.

Comment: Thanks so much, create two format types and convert them piecemeal was a brilliant idea. Didn't understand your code, but I did it my, simplified way, and it worked perfectly!Thanks so much!

Comment: The ‘pd.to_datetime’ part should be simple enough. To check what the combine_first does, I suggest you check out the documentation and play around with it a bit. You can also do the steps I suggest one by one.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a date_parser to read_excel:

```
dateparser = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, dayfirst=True)

pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', date_parser = dateparser)
```

Comment: That worked for 26/05/20, but  12/05/2020 is read like 5 Dec 2020

Comment: @Bowcoy hm, try with this dateparser? `dateparser = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d/%m/Y')`

Comment: I tried. It generates an error because of text in the column. Without text (I manually removed it for test ) it gives the same result - 2/05/2020 is read like 5 Dec 2020

Comment: @Bowcoy, then I am sorry. I cannot reproduce your problem on my machine.

Comment: It should be `dateparser = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d/%m/%Y')` (with a `%` before `Y`)

Answer (score 0):

I think, first you should import the file without date parsing then convert it to date format using following:

```
df['column3']= pd.to_datetime(df['column3'], errors='coerce')
```

Hope this will work

Comment: I tried **parse_dates=False** but it didn't work. I think it's because in the file I uploading to pandas it's already in Date format

Comment: Don't use parse_dates argument while loading it into pandas dataframe